# How to deal with a postgres text column that holds json/array data

Tags: json, postgresql, arraylist

I have a postgres (version 11) table that holds vehicle data. The data gets populated from a CSV file. One of the fields called mot_history is a text field, and is sometimes NULL or has the value of 'No MOT data available' but often looks like this:

```json
[{"completedDate": "2019-05-08T13:38:21+00:00", "expiryDate": "2020-11-07T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 89178}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Non obligatory mirror damaged ()", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, {"completedDate": "2019-04-29T08:39:45+00:00", "expiryDate": null, "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 88909}, "passed": false, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Front Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Offside Front Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Rear Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view (3.3 (b) (ii))", "type": "FAIL"}]}, {"completedDate": "2018-05-01T14:33:15+00:00", "expiryDate": "2019-04-30T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 77880}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror damaged, but not seriously affecting the rear view (8.1.2a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Offside Rear  jacking  point  missing", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, {"completedDate": "2017-04-26T08:41:07+00:00", "expiryDate": "2018-04-26T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 66658}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Non obligatory mirror damaged ()", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 40mm circle outside zone 'A' (8.3.1d)", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, {"completedDate": "2016-04-27T09:46:44+00:00", "expiryDate": "2017-04-26T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 54490}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror damaged, but not seriously affecting the rear view (8.1.2a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Front brake disc worn, pitted or scored, but not seriously weakened (3.5.1i)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "brake warning lamp illuminated", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, {"completedDate": "2015-04-20T10:45:28+00:00", "expiryDate": "2016-04-19T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 42143}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 10mm circle within zone 'A' (8.3.1a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "nearside obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view", "type": "USER ENTERED"}, {"text": "parking brake noisy on application", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}, {"completedDate": "2015-04-15T12:42:31+00:00", "expiryDate": null, "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 41921}, "passed": false, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Inner Front Brake pad(s) less than 1.5 mm thick (3.5.1g)", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Inner Rear Brake pad(s) less than 1.5 mm thick (3.5.1g)", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 10mm circle within zone 'A' (8.3.1a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "nearside obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view", "type": "USER ENTERED"}, {"text": "parking brake noisy on application", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}, {"completedDate": "2014-04-09T17:17:55+00:00", "expiryDate": "2015-04-08T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 29857}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Rear Tyre worn close to the legal limit (4.1.E.1)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "both front tyres worn on inner edges", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}]
[{"completedDate": "2017-06-22T07:40:58+00:00", "expiryDate": "2018-07-01T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 23985}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": []}]
[{"completedDate": "2020-03-05T12:11:13+00:00", "expiryDate": "2021-03-25T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 58804}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": []}, {"completedDate": "2019-03-26T13:56:21+00:00", "expiryDate": "2020-03-25T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 53674}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": []}, {"completedDate": "2018-10-27T10:39:06+00:00", "expiryDate": "2019-10-29T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 52580}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Rear Brake pad(s) wearing thin  1.5 mm (1.1.13 (a) (ii))", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Nearside Front Tyre slightly damaged/cracking or perishing  Tyre cracking. (5.2.3 (d) (ii))", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Offside Front Tyre slightly damaged/cracking or perishing  Tyre cracking. (5.2.3 (d) (ii))", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Nearside Front Tyre worn close to legal limit/worn on edge  2.5 mm (5.2.3 (e))", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Offside Front Tyre worn close to legal limit/worn on edge  2.9 mm (5.2.3 (e))", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Nearside Front Outer Tyre worn close to legal limit/worn on edge  Worn outer edge. (5.2.3 (e))", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}]
```

Here is the above slightly more formatted to give you a better idea of what the structure is

```
[
    {"completedDate": "2019-05-08T13:38:21+00:00", "expiryDate": "2020-11-07T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 9999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 89178}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": 
        [
            {"text": "Nearside Non obligatory mirror damaged ()", "type": "ADVISORY"}
        ]
    }, 
    {"completedDate": "2019-04-29T08:39:45+00:00", "expiryDate": null, "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 88909}, "passed": false, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Front Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Offside Front Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Rear Tyre has a cut in excess of the requirements deep enough to reach the ply or cords (5.2.3 (d) (i))", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view (3.3 (b) (ii))", "type": "FAIL"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2018-05-01T14:33:15+00:00", "expiryDate": "2019-04-30T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 77880}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror damaged, but not seriously affecting the rear view (8.1.2a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Offside Rear  jacking  point  missing", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2017-04-26T08:41:07+00:00", "expiryDate": "2018-04-26T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 66658}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Non obligatory mirror damaged ()", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 40mm circle outside zone 'A' (8.3.1d)", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2016-04-27T09:46:44+00:00", "expiryDate": "2017-04-26T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 54490}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Obligatory mirror damaged, but not seriously affecting the rear view (8.1.2a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "Front brake disc worn, pitted or scored, but not seriously weakened (3.5.1i)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "brake warning lamp illuminated", "type": "ADVISORY"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2015-04-20T10:45:28+00:00", "expiryDate": "2016-04-19T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 42143}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 10mm circle within zone 'A' (8.3.1a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "nearside obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view", "type": "USER ENTERED"}, {"text": "parking brake noisy on application", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2015-04-15T12:42:31+00:00", "expiryDate": null, "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 41921}, "passed": false, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Nearside Inner Front Brake pad(s) less than 1.5 mm thick (3.5.1g)", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Nearside Inner Rear Brake pad(s) less than 1.5 mm thick (3.5.1g)", "type": "FAIL"}, {"text": "Windscreen has damage to an area less than a 10mm circle within zone 'A' (8.3.1a)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "nearside obligatory mirror seriously damaged, affecting the rear view", "type": "USER ENTERED"}, {"text": "parking brake noisy on application", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}, 
    {"completedDate": "2014-04-09T17:17:55+00:00", "expiryDate": "2015-04-08T00:00:00+00:00", "testNumber": 999999999, "odomoter": {"unit": "mi", "value": 29857}, "passed": true, "rfcAndComments": [{"text": "Rear Tyre worn close to the legal limit (4.1.E.1)", "type": "ADVISORY"}, {"text": "both front tyres worn on inner edges", "type": "USER ENTERED"}]}
]
```

I don't have any control over the format of the input data as it comes to us externally, but I wondered if it's possible using SQL to get at the values stored in this JSON/array like structure. For example let's say I wanted to return the expiry date for a vehicle that had passed it's MOT. I know I could probably do this by slicing and dicing the text but wondered if there was a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of research, I think something like this will do it

```
with data as
(
    select mot_history::jsonb as x 
    from my_table where length(mot_history) > 50

)   
select item_object->'passed',item_object->'expiryDate',position from data,jsonb_array_elements(x) with ordinality arr(item_object, position) 
where item_object->'passed' = 'true'
```

Comment: That will work if the condition `length(mot_history) > 50` is always fulfilled for correct JSON values.